# Update ASCX from ASPX using delegates

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to separate all DB calls required by ASCX.cs to call only from ASPX.cs, I am trying it with delegate and events.

my ASCX.cs has

```
namespace x.xx.xy.xyy.xyyy
{
public partial class PaymentItem : UserControlBase
{      
    public delegate void Handler(Dictionary<string, string> keyvalues);
    public event Handler aPICall;     
}
}
```

my ASPX.cs has

```
namespace x.xx.xz.xzz.xzzz
{
public partial class PaymentItemPopUp
{
    protected global::x.xx.xy.xyy.xyyy.PaymentItem ucPaymentItem;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ucPaymentItem.aPICall += new PaymentItem.Handler(ServiceAPICAll);

    }
protected void ServiceAPICAll(Dictionary<string, string> keyvalues){

}
}
}
```

I am getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' when compiler hits the following line 
this.ucPaymentItem.aPICall += new PaymentItem.Handler(ServiceAPICAll);

I suppose the issue from the following line

protected global::x.xx.xy.xyy.xyyy.PaymentItem ucPaymentItem;

any idea?

Comment: Are you placing this UserControl onto the page or initialising through code? If the latter then 'protected global::x.xx.xy.xyy.xyyy.PaymentItem ucPaymentItem; = new global::x.xx.xy.xyy.xyyy.PaymentItem()' maybe all you need...

Comment: Are you trying to route the ASCX calls through to ASPX so as not to duplicate logic or is there another reason?

Comment: @SeanCocteau - placing this UserControl onto the page
@ Dave Becker - trying to route the ASCX calls through to ASPX, to make the control to be used by other developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now.

I removed designer generated code for my user control in my aspx page

my ASPX.designer.cs

```
//protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl PaymentItem1;
```

Then I changed like the following

my ASPx.cs

```
protected global::x.xx.xy.xyy.xyyy.PaymentItem  PaymentItem1;
```

My ASPX

```
<%@ Register Src="~/_xy/xyy/xyyy/PaymentItem.ascx" TagName="PaymentItem" TagPrefix="uc1"  %>
 <uc1:PaymentItem runat="server" ID="PaymentItem1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always declared my delegates outside of the class like this

```
public delegate void PaymentItemHandler(...)
public partial class PaymentItem : UserControlBase 
{
  public PaymentItemHandler OnHandler { get; set;}
}
```

then use it like you already do

```
this.ucPaymentItem.OnHandler += new PaymentItemHandler(ServiceAPICall)
```

Comment: Oh hang on. You're using 'event' don't you just need to do `this.usPaymentItem.aPICall += ServiceAPICall;`